# Running python script with python3 using ./

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, command-line-interface

How do I run a python script with python 3.7 by using this syntax: `./main.py`?

By default, it runs with python 2.7 and thus I'm forced to run the script with `python3 ./main.py`

I am on MacOS.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: Thanks, I'm not used to write languages like Python, I'm more a JavaScript guy and almost never see shebangs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could place a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) on the first line of the file to make it executable (by python3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

Comment: Thanks ! As I said as a comment on my post, I'm not used to write languages that use shebangs, and never thought about that, that's a simple and good solution